# Parsing XML to js data, how to acces specific tag?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, dom, d3.js

### Situation

For a database analysis tool I need to parse a bunch of generated XML files (hibernate reverse engineered XML files) to javascript for visualization purposes. As I am very new to javascript being a java developer, I am trying to take small steps at a time. Eventually I want to parse the xml files to d3.js force layout graph, but thats a bridge to far for me for now.

### Reproduce

Given the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src=d3-queue.js></script>
<script>

var q = d3_queue.queue();

// TODO 1: for each xml in folder xyz ... defer(d3.xml, "dynamicvalue", "application/xml") instead of hard coded
    .defer(d3.xml, "Actor.hbm.xml", "application/xml")
    .defer(d3.xml, "Film.hbm.xml", "application/xml")
    .defer(d3.xml, "Category.hbm.xml", "application/xml")
    .await(analyze);   

// obviously the function parameter need to be dynamic and not hard coded actor, film, category...
function analyze(error, actor,film,category) {
// TODO 2: for each read xml do ...

  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(category)
  console.log("XML Root Tag Name: " + category.documentElement.tagName)
  console.log("Checking Child Nodes: " + category.documentElement.childNodes[0].hasChildNodes)
  console.log("First Child: " + category.documentElement.childNodes[1].firstChild.tagName)
  console.log("Node Value: " + category.documentElement.childNodes[0].attributes.getNamedItem("id").nodeValue)      

}
</script>
```

And given the following example .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 15-mrt-2016 20:29:28 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.2.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="nl.sander.mieras.localhost.sakila.Category" table="category" catalog="sakila">
        <id name="categoryId" type="java.lang.Byte">
            <column name="category_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="25" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpdate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="last_update" length="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="filmCategories" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="category_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="nl.sander.mieras.localhost.sakila.FilmCategory" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### Question

How do I dynamically *read the value* from the table name (here it is: "category") and save it to var nodes?

I have been stuck on parsing the xml to the correct js data for quite a while now, so any push in the right direction would be amazing.

### Research

I have tried the examples from http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript/ but I am not getting expected results. Those expected results would be for the child node something like `<id name="categoryId" type="java.lang.Byte">`.

Also I tried extensively to get things working based answer given by @Lars Grammel on the question [How to import XML data using d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682856/how-to-import-xml-data-using-d3-js) . Even though the links and answer is great, I can't make it work for my situation (not enough knowhow)

The first "end" goal is to create a force layout with all the table names as nodes (with no links yet, links will eventually be the one-to-many and the many-to-one mappings), as shown in https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1080941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to read out the value of the "table"-attribute?

You can do it width jQuery for example:

```
$.get("some.xml", function(d){
    console.log($(d).find("class").attr("table"));
});
```

this will put out: "category"

Comment: Thank you @thebiz, this helps me alot. One small part of my question remains. Am I correct in assuming that the string "category" is now saved to the d variable. How do I save it to (say) a var nodes with nodes being an array of multiple values?

Comment: I am gonna accept your answer and ask my remaining question in a new topic. Thanks alot @thebiz for you help!

Comment: What do you **exactly** want to store in the nodes-array?

If you have an array called "nodes", you can push
the value easily in it like this:

`nodes.push($(d).find("class").attr("table"));`

Comment: The array of objects nodes should look like this:

`var nodes = [{ "id": 0,"label": "Film"}`

so I have tried the following:

`var nodes = [];

  $.get("Film.hbm.xml", function(d){     
    var table = $(d).find("class").attr("table")    
    console.log(table)    
    var node = {
     // How to assign index of the nodes array as id ?
     id: 0,
     label: table
    };
    console.log(node);    
    nodes.push(node);
    console.log(nodes);
});`

This however is not very dynamic

Comment: `nodes.push({"id":nodes.length,"label":$(d).find("class").attr("table")});`

What do you mean by dynamic? Do you want to push other nodes beside "class" into the nodes array?

Comment: Thank you for your answers and sorry if I am not clear in my comments.
I have multiple .xml files on the server. I want to read all these xml files, for each xml file I want to add the table name (that is found by your awesome help) with an index (index 0 if its the first xml file, index 1 if its the second xml file, index 3 if its the third xml file, etc) to the var nodes array. This is what I mean with dynamic.

Comment: with `"id":nodes.length` you will set the index for each object you push into the nodes array. this is fully dynamic.

Comment: Yep it works very nice.

`var nodes = [];

  $.get("Film.hbm.xml", function(d){    
    nodes.push({"id":nodes.length,
     "label":$(d).find("class").attr("table")
     });    
});
  
  console.log(nodes);`

Now I will try to figure out how to make it save to the var nodes declared at the top of the class...ehm script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106741/discussion-between-sander-m-and-thebiz).